# Understanding ADF Data Sets

Tags: azure-data-factory

I understand that that within Azure Data Factory, a dataset is a view of some source data. Can you create a single dataset from a query joining two source tables? Or do you have to create two datasets, a data flow using a join transformation, to create a third dataset, as the sink of that transformation, that is the desired result?

It appears that source tables are not a thing in ADF, just datasets (which are just tables)? I find this highly confusing and perhaps I do not understand the higher context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A DataSet is not a view of the data, it's a pointer to a location, and optionally a description of the schema found at that location. In your case, a pointer to a table, so yes you would need a DataSet for each SOURCE table, with a Schema. You can JOIN them together in a Data Flow, then you would need another DataSet for the SINK. Depending on the Sink type, you may or may not need to create a Schema.

I'm assuming some SQL variant for the tables - if so, and if the two tables are in the same Database, then I would recommend doing the JOIN in the SQL as it will be faster and more efficient. If the Sink is also in the same database, then you'll get the most mileage out of a Stored Procedure rather than a Data Flow.

Comment: Thank you. So it's most likely easiest to simply create a view within SQL and do the join there and create a dataset from that?

Comment: I've never created a DataSet from a View, so I'm not sure if Views show up in the Tables list or not. If that does not work, your Data Flow can use a SELECT Query which can reference the View.